# Modify function in resource model to do do an 'equals' search in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7

I have the following function in my Resource Collection which is as follows:

```
public function searchByNameOnly($term)
{
    $this->addFieldToFilter(array('organisation_name'),array(
        array('like' => $term.'%'),
        array('like' => $term.'%')
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

I want to amend this so it isn't using the LIKE but rather an equals, so in a sense the SQL equivalent would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE organisation_name = 'ACME Inc';
```

How should I amend the function above to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'eq' instead of 'like':

```
$this->addFieldToFilter(array('organisation_name'),array(
    array('eq' => $term.'%'),
    array('eq' => $term.'%')
));
```